# How to select all occurrences of regular expression in a single field of SQL

Tags: sql, regex

I need to get list of all occurrences of specific regular expression in a single record of SQL

for example I have record like this:

```
=> 'Dear {0}, your account will expire in {1} days'
```

I stored this string in a table and I want to select all occurrences of '{something}'

in this example:

```
=>     {0}
       {1}
```

what should I do ???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

thanks everybody
I've just found answer of my question

```
Declare @InputText  nVarChar(100)
;

Select  @InputText  =   'Dear {Token 0}, your account will expire in {Token 1} days'
;

with    Tokens  AS
(
    SELECT  SUBSTRING(@InputText,PATINDEX('%{%',@InputText)+1,PATINDEX('%}%',@InputText)-PATINDEX('%{%',@InputText)-1)  As  Token
    ,   SUBSTRING(@InputText,PATINDEX('%}%',@InputText)+1,LEN(@InputText))                      As  New
    ,   PATINDEX('%{%',SUBSTRING(@InputText,PATINDEX('%}%',@InputText)+1,LEN(@InputText)))              As  [NextStart]
    ,   PATINDEX('%}%',SUBSTRING(@InputText,PATINDEX('%}%',@InputText)+1,LEN(@InputText)))              As  [NextEnd]

    Union   All

    Select  SUBSTRING(Tokens.New,Tokens.[NextStart]+1,Tokens.[NextEnd]-Tokens.[NextStart]-1)
    ,   SUBSTRING(Tokens.New,Tokens.[NextEnd]+1,LEN(Tokens.New))
    ,   PATINDEX('%{%',SUBSTRING(Tokens.New,Tokens.[NextEnd]+1,LEN(Tokens.New)))
    ,   PATINDEX('%}%',SUBSTRING(Tokens.New,Tokens.[NextEnd]+1,LEN(Tokens.New)))
    From    Tokens
    Where   Tokens.[NextStart]  != 0
)   Select  Token
    From    Tokens
```

and the result would be like this:

```
=>
    Token 0
    Token 1
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You don't "get list of all occurrences of specific regular expression", but use regular expression to find occurences of specific string in another string :).
2. {0} and {1} is different from {something}. If you want only digits between {}, you'd use `\{(\d+)\}` but if there may be letters, digits and underscore, it'd be `\{(\w+)\}`
3. You really should specify what database system are you using. Are you sure it even supports regex?

Comment: thank you for your answers
but I'm using sql server and also I don't want to replace these regular expressions with some thin from the other table I just want to list them, and they may be more or less in the other input texts